# what is wrangler port in data transformation in NIFI?

Tags: apache-nifi, kylo

I would like to know what is Wrangler input/cleanup port in DATA TRANSFORMATION template . for the data ingest template nifi providing input and clean up ports , where we can define properties, directories and all.

But when comes to data transformation, not able to understand what is Wrangler ports and from where we are getting data to transform and which table being using from the data source.

kindly provide the your suggestions / links / resources .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The to-wrangler-port and to-wrangler-cleanup-port ports are NiFi output ports. They allow for connecting processors between process groups. The are connected to the wrangler-input-port and wrangler-cleanup-port NiFi input ports, respectively, in the data-transformation reusable template flow.

The Data Transformation template in Kylo actually contains two NiFi templates. The first NiFi template contains the information from your feed such as the list of transformations. The second NiFi template contains processors that are used by all Data Transformation feeds. This encourages reusability and make it easier to ensure that business policies are being adhered to.

The Kylo team has a "Connecting to a Reusable Flow" video that explains these concepts in more detail:
https://kylo.io/tutorials.html
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vj641MRJCd8

Comment: thank you so much , would you please tell me the process to add the commit release high water mark in data transformation template by putting water mark value to high  as like we do data ingest . because i need to get the incremental/updated  data .

Comment: Please open a new question about high water marks, or refer to the Kylo documentation: http://kylo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how-to-guides/NiFiProcessorsDocs.html#high-water-mark-processors